# Why is my Django jQuery button not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, button

I am very new to jQuery and trying to make a simple app which allows people to like photos using Ajax call. Here are the relevant parts:

photo.html:

```
{% if pic %}

<img class="pic" src="/static/assets/{{pic}}" />
<br />

{% csrf_token %}
<input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" />

<p id="likes"> </p> people liked this
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def like_photo(request, pic_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if pic_id:
            uid = request.user.id
            p=UserPic.objects.get(id=pic_id)

            if Liker.objects.filter(user=uid, pic=pic_id):

                p.likes -=1
                p.save()
                Liker.objects.filter(user= uid, pic=pic_id).delete()
            else:

                p.likes +=1
                p.save()
                newliker = Liker(user= uid, pic=pic_id)
                newliker.save()
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['likes']= p.likes
        return render_to_response('photo.html', args)
```

like.js

```
$(function(){

    $('#like').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var post_id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "'/photo/like/'+ post_id",
            data: { 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: likeSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#likes').html(data);
}
```

I can see in Firebug that jQuery and like.js are loaded on the page but clicking the like button does not have any effect according to Firebug's XHR.

The app works perfectly fine without AJAX call, that is, when I use a simple anchor in the template:

```
<p><a href="/photo/like/{{pic.id}}">Like</a></p>
```

Comment: just noticed an error, `"'/photo/like/'+ post_id"` is incorrect, you want `"/photo/like/" + post_id`. notice it isn't all surrounded by quotes

Comment: @Eru that is almost certainly the problem, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman apparently that was not the only problem. the button still  does not send post requests, according to Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

there was a small (but significant!) bug in your code

`"'/photo/like/'+ post_id"` is incorrect, you want `"/photo/like/" + post_id`. notice it isn't all surrounded by quotes

Comment: After correcting the line you mentioned, the button seems to work on the browser. thanks. but it still does not affect the the number of likes. In firebug nothing seem to be passed to the views when I click the button.

Comment: Hmm you should be getting I'd with this.get('id')

Answer (score 0):

Ok I manged to get in work like this:

photo.html:

```
{% if pic %}


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#like').click(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var post_id = {{pic.id}};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/photo/like/" + post_id ,
            data: { 
        'pic_id': post_id,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: likeSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'    
        });            
    });    
});

function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{     
    $('#likes').html(data);
}

</script>

<img class="pic" src="/static/assets/{{pic}}" />
<br />

{% csrf_token %}
<input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" />

<p id="likes"> {{pic.likes}} &nbsp;liked this </p>

{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def like_photo(request, pic_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if pic_id:
            uid = request.user.id
            p=UserPic.objects.get(id=pic_id)

            #if UserPic.objects.filter(liked_by__user__contains=uid):
            if Liker.objects.filter(user=uid, pic=pic_id):
                #return HttpResponse('You have already liked!')

                p.likes -=1
                p.save()
                Liker.objects.filter(user= uid, pic=pic_id).delete()
            else:

                p.likes +=1
                p.save()
                newliker = Liker(user= uid, pic=pic_id)
                newliker.save()

            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['likes'] = p.likes

        return render_to_response('userpics/likes.html', args)
```

also needed to create a specific html for ajax call:

likes.html

```
{% if likes > 0 %}
{{likes}} liked this
{% else %}
crap
{% endif %}
```

Not sure if it is the best way but it works. 
I wish I could use a more elegant json to return the likes digit and get rid of the likes.html but could not figure out how to do so.

Also, for some strange reason the script does not work when I import it externally at base.html:

```
<script src="{% static "assets/js/likes.js" %}"></script>
```

though firebug says that it is loaded on the page.

Your suggestions to improve the answer are welcomed.

Comment: Note: since simplejason is removed from util in Django 1.7+ you need to simply 'import json' instead of 'forom django.util import simplejason'